# Block options of a Dropdown with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to block options with js. Here is source code of the site:

[image: see attached screenshot]

Just wanted to block first 2 values.

```
<select name="ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl0‌​0$cp$cbRodzajUslugi\‌​&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&‌​#39;, 0)" id="cp_cbRodzajUslugi" style="width:200px;">
  <option selected="selected" value="-1"></option>
  <option value="708">National visa - others</option>
  <option value="1156">National visa - students</option> 
  <option value="1157">National visa - work</option> 
</select>
```

I want to block 708 and 1108 values. it would be better if anyone write that code for me

Comment: `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: Just adding the `disabled` attribute will work as well.

Comment: this is the code 
<select name="ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cp_cbRodzajUslugi" style="width:200px;">
         <option selected="selected" value="-1"></option>
         <option value="708">National visa - others</option>
         <option value="1156">National visa - students</option>
         <option value="1157">National visa - work</option>

        </select>

i want to block 708 and 1108 values. it would be better if anyone write that code for me. thanks

Comment: `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#cp_cbRodzajUslugi [value="708"],#cp_cbRodzajUslugi [value="1108"]')).forEach(function(ele){ 
  ele.disabled = true; })`

Comment: not working in greasemonkey (addon for running scripts) :(

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MdAlJummanShithil try `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll([value="708"],[value="1108"]')).forEach(function(ele){ ele.disabled = true; })`

Answer (score 0):

Get the options by using attribute equals selector and update the disabled property.

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#cp_cbRodzajUslugi [value="708"],#cp_cbRodzajUslugi [value="1108"]')).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.disabled = true;
})
```

```html
<select name="ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cp_cbRodzajUslugi" style="width:200px;">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="-1"></option>
                                    <option value="708">National visa - others</option>
                                    <option value="1156">National visa - students</option>
                                    <option value="1157">National visa - work</option>                                    <option value="1108">National visa - work</option>
</select>
```